# LLVM Segmentation fault on basic function pass

Tags: c++, clang, llvm

I'm completely new to LLVM. I tried to follow the functions in the [following article](https://www.cs.cornell.edu/~asampson/blog/llvm.html). This is the function pass that is defined there:

```
#include "llvm/Pass.h"
#include "llvm/IR/Function.h"
#include "llvm/Support/raw_ostream.h"
#include "llvm/IR/LegacyPassManager.h"
#include "llvm/IR/InstrTypes.h"
#include "llvm/Transforms/IPO/PassManagerBuilder.h"
#include "llvm/IR/IRBuilder.h"
#include "llvm/Transforms/Utils/BasicBlockUtils.h"
using namespace llvm;

namespace {
  struct SkeletonPass : public FunctionPass {
    static char ID;
    SkeletonPass() : FunctionPass(ID) {}

    virtual bool runOnFunction(Function &F) {
      for (auto &B : F) {
        for (auto &I : B) {
          if (auto *op = dyn_cast<BinaryOperator>(&I)) {
            // Insert at the point where the instruction `op` appears.
            IRBuilder<> builder(op);

            // Make a multiply with the same operands as `op`.
            Value *lhs = op->getOperand(0);
            Value *rhs = op->getOperand(1);
            Value *mul = builder.CreateMul(lhs, rhs);

            // Everywhere the old instruction was used as an operand, use our
            // new multiply instruction instead.
            for (auto &U : op->uses()) {
              User *user = U.getUser();  // A User is anything with operands.
              user->setOperand(U.getOperandNo(), mul);
            }

            // We modified the code.
            return true;
          }
        }
      }

      return false;
    }
  };
}

char SkeletonPass::ID = 0;

// Automatically enable the pass.
// http://adriansampson.net/blog/clangpass.html
static void registerSkeletonPass(const PassManagerBuilder &,
                         legacy::PassManagerBase &PM) {
  PM.add(new SkeletonPass());
}
static RegisterStandardPasses
  RegisterMyPass(PassManagerBuilder::EP_EarlyAsPossible,
                 registerSkeletonPass);
```

Then compiled the file:

```
$ cd llvm-pass-skeleton
$ mkdir build
$ cd build
$ cmake ..  # Generate the Makefile.
$ make  # Actually build the pass.
```

And run it using:

```
/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang -Xclang -load -Xclang build/skeleton/libSkeletonPass.so example.c
```

Where example.c is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, const char** argv) {
    int num;
    scanf("%i", &num);
    printf("%i\n", num + 2); 
    return 0;
}
```

I'm on Mac OS X Mojave and I installed LLVM using homebrew and put it in my PATH.

I get the following error message

```
clang version 9.0.0 (tags/RELEASE_900/final)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin18.7.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/local/Cellar/llvm/9.0.0_1/bin
 "/usr/local/Cellar/llvm/9.0.0_1/bin/clang-9" -cc1 -triple x86_64-apple-macosx10.14.0 -Wdeprecated-objc-isa-usage -Werror=deprecated-objc-isa-usage -emit-obj -mrelax-all -disable-free -disable-llvm-verifier -discard-value-names -main-file-name example.c -mrelocation-model pic -pic-level 2 -mthread-model posix -mdisable-fp-elim -masm-verbose -munwind-tables -target-cpu penryn -dwarf-column-info -debugger-tuning=lldb -ggnu-pubnames -target-linker-version 512.4 -v -resource-dir /usr/local/Cellar/llvm/9.0.0_1/lib/clang/9.0.0 -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -internal-isystem /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/local/include -internal-isystem /usr/local/Cellar/llvm/9.0.0_1/lib/clang/9.0.0/include -internal-externc-isystem /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include -fdebug-compilation-dir /Users/BN/Documents/Library/CS/Compilers/LLVM/llvm-pass-skeleton -ferror-limit 19 -fmessage-length 80 -stack-protector 1 -fblocks -fencode-extended-block-signature -fregister-global-dtors-with-atexit -fobjc-runtime=macosx-10.14.0 -fmax-type-align=16 -fdiagnostics-show-option -fcolor-diagnostics -load build/skeleton/libSkeletonPass.so -o /var/folders/cf/1_hzh5h91x90j4xx_h1mlb4w0000gp/T/example-4b27ba.o -x c example.c
clang -cc1 version 9.0.0 based upon LLVM 9.0.0 default target x86_64-apple-darwin18.7.0
ignoring nonexistent directory "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/local/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/Library/Frameworks"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/local/Cellar/llvm/9.0.0_1/lib/clang/9.0.0/include
 /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include
 /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks (framework directory)
End of search list.
Stack dump:
0.  Program arguments: /usr/local/Cellar/llvm/9.0.0_1/bin/clang-9 -cc1 -triple x86_64-apple-macosx10.14.0 -Wdeprecated-objc-isa-usage -Werror=deprecated-objc-isa-usage -emit-obj -mrelax-all -disable-free -disable-llvm-verifier -discard-value-names -main-file-name example.c -mrelocation-model pic -pic-level 2 -mthread-model posix -mdisable-fp-elim -masm-verbose -munwind-tables -target-cpu penryn -dwarf-column-info -debugger-tuning=lldb -ggnu-pubnames -target-linker-version 512.4 -v -resource-dir /usr/local/Cellar/llvm/9.0.0_1/lib/clang/9.0.0 -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -internal-isystem /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/local/include -internal-isystem /usr/local/Cellar/llvm/9.0.0_1/lib/clang/9.0.0/include -internal-externc-isystem /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include -fdebug-compilation-dir /Users/BN/Documents/Library/CS/Compilers/LLVM/llvm-pass-skeleton -ferror-limit 19 -fmessage-length 80 -stack-protector 1 -fblocks -fencode-extended-block-signature -fregister-global-dtors-with-atexit -fobjc-runtime=macosx-10.14.0 -fmax-type-align=16 -fdiagnostics-show-option -fcolor-diagnostics -load build/skeleton/libSkeletonPass.so -o /var/folders/cf/1_hzh5h91x90j4xx_h1mlb4w0000gp/T/example-4b27ba.o -x c example.c 
0  clang-9                  0x00000001071fba46 llvm::sys::PrintStackTrace(llvm::raw_ostream&) + 40
1  clang-9                  0x00000001071fbe98 SignalHandler(int) + 180
2  libsystem_platform.dylib 0x00007fff6f2aeb5d _sigtramp + 29
3  libsystem_platform.dylib 0x0000000000000001 _sigtramp + 18446603338651079873
4  clang-9                  0x0000000106e94485 llvm::object_deleter<llvm::SmallVector<std::__1::pair<llvm::PassManagerBuilder::ExtensionPointTy, std::__1::function<void (llvm::PassManagerBuilder const&, llvm::legacy::PassManagerBase&)> >, 8u> >::call(void*) + 19
5  clang-9                  0x00000001071abc95 llvm::llvm_shutdown() + 53
6  clang-9                  0x0000000107193061 llvm::InitLLVM::~InitLLVM() + 15
7  clang-9                  0x0000000106034857 main + 7249
8  libdyld.dylib            0x00007fff6f0c33d5 start + 1
clang-9: error: unable to execute command: Segmentation fault: 11
clang-9: error: clang frontend command failed due to signal (use -v to see invocation)
clang version 9.0.0 (tags/RELEASE_900/final)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin18.7.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/local/Cellar/llvm/9.0.0_1/bin
clang-9: note: diagnostic msg: PLEASE submit a bug report to https://bugs.llvm.org/ and include the crash backtrace, preprocessed source, and associated run script.
clang-9: error: unable to execute command: Segmentation fault: 11
clang-9: note: diagnostic msg: Error generating preprocessed source(s).
```

The error message states that the two non-existant directories `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/local/include` and `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/Library/Frameworks` will be ignored. These directories are actually installed under `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include` and `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library`, respectively. Not sure whether this is relevant and how to tell Clang to look in those locations.

Can somebody help me with this please?

Comment: I'm afraid I cannot help you, but I can offer a small suggestion: Build LLVM yourself, and build it with debugging. That's 99% likely to gain you a helpful message before/instead of the segfault.

Comment: I can't help either but I would suspect that the the original `BinaryOperator` `op` has ownership of its operands and that reusing them in `mul` results in a double deletion of them. Maybe you can extract the operands or simply clone them before reusing them.

Comment: @arnt Would I need to only build llvm or also Clang?

Comment: Oh, I know what the problem is. You're modifying a list while iterating over it. B. That particular list class doesn't tolerate that. Yes, you need to build clang too, but that's no extra trouble, just extra time, since they're in the same source tree.